# iOS - Do action on TodayViewController (Widget) only once a day

Tags: ios, objective-c, widget

I am currently doing some stats on our Widget.

I want to be able to count the number of visits in the `viewWillAppear`method of the widget but only once a day at max.

First of all, I thought about a Boolean, but it will be deallocated so I will lose the reference of this Bool value right ?

Then I was wondering if  `dispatch_once` could do the trick in my situation.

```
static dispatch_once_t once;
    dispatch_once(&once, ^ {

    });
```

What do you guys think ?

I don't want my stats to be inaccurate because the user load and display the Widget from the Home Page hundred of times in a day.

That is why I want to cap the count method only once a day.

**PS :** I am developing with Objective C

Comment: Basically you will loose everything, which is not persistent, when the app is terminated. So, I think you will have to store (persist) the information if viewWillAppear was already called on a specific day or not. It's also a questions, what is your purpose? Some kind of analytics? Did you think about using a analytics tool (like GA or whatever)?

Comment: In the preferences utilities I guess ? Actually I am already using analytics tool, but I don't want the method to send stat to be called every time the Widget is load

Comment: That's what I am talking about :)
Sorry I called it with the name of my Class.
If you want accepted answer, write one. 
Thank you

Comment: So you could for example store the date in NSUserDefaults, each time you sent the event. Then just check if the date was not today, send the event, update the date to today. I'm not good in explaining this, but hope you got the point? :)

Comment: I got it @D4Rk :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just store the current date each time you sent the event. Then just check if the stored date is today. 
If not, send the event and update the stored date accordingly.

Example in Swift (not tested):

```
let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
let dateOfLastEvent = defaults.string(forKey: "DateOfLastEvent")

let currentDate = Date()
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyyMMdd"

let currentDateString = formatter.string(from: currentDate)

if (currentDateString != dateOfLastEvent) {
    // Send the event
    defaults.set(currentDateString, forKey: "DateOfLastEvent")
}
```